# A large table and request time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

assume we have a table with 100 million records in it. while I do a query. simple select on it, It will take 0.5 second to return data to me.

Now if 100 users simultaneously request the same query. does it take 50 seconds foreach user to respond? ( 0.5 * 100 )

Comment: Don't use order by
Use sql cache for same queries

Comment: no. each user gets its own thread and the table will be accessed in parallel

Comment: I removed the sql-server-performance tag, because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: @akuzminsky, normally, How many parallel request MySQL can handle at the same time?

Comment: Check out benchmarks from Oracle https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/mysql_5_6_is_a

The max throughput is achieved with ~128  parallel threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, databases do not necessarily scale like that.  They can be better.  Or they can be worse.

If you have such a large table, then you are accessing the rows using an index.  Presumably, this index is in memory.  There are several components to doing this simple search, such as:

- Compiling the initial query (from SQL to what the engine actually executes).
- Searching for the rows to be returned
- Gathering the data from those rows
- Returning the data to the user

Different stages are going to have different CPU, I/O, and network requirements.  My guess is that on your machine, running a single query is not max'ing out any of these resources.  You can probably run a second similar query with minimal impact.  And maybe a third.  But not an unlimited number.

Eventually, the concurrent queries will start to interfere with each other, in some way.  This interference can result in non-linear performance degradation, particularly if it involves using up all available database memory and swapping components out to disk.  You would have to test this on your system if you really wanted to know the threshold.

By the way, this is a very simple example.  You only have one table (as you describe it), so you don't have multiple object contenting for memory.  You are not doing any data modifications, so you don't have to deal with locking issues.

Answer (score 0):

1)Don't use order by
2)Use sql cache for same queries

Comment: Actually query cache is protected by a single mutex, so all requests to it will be serialized. So, don't use the query cache on highly concurrent load